# How can I use Google Apps Script to make multiple versions of a similar form with one drop down field based on a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I work for a summer program that hosts residential academic classes for high school students. We have around 1,000 students and around 100 teachers. This year, we are implementing a weekly feedback form that teachers will use to assess students on their classroom performance.

The form is the same for all teachers, but we only want each teacher to be able to enter data about their own students. Since there's so many teachers and students and we want to track and report on this later, there is a large risk associated with allowing teachers to manually enter names.

My vision is that each teacher gets their own form (i.e. "Mr. Smith's weekly assessment form") and that the forms are identical except for the first question, which would be a drop-down with the 10-12 students that teacher has. The teacher would select a student and then fill out the relevant information.

If I had a Google Sheet in the following structure (the structure could be changed if that would be easier for code to deal with), how could I write code that would generate a unique form for each teacher and then create an initial question with student names based on the sheet?

[image: Sample google sheet structure]

In this case, Mr. Smith would get a form where his drop-down for students had Jack and Jill. Mrs. Jones would get a form with Robby and Sally as choices.

Also, if there's a way to have all these generated forms save responses to one Google Sheet (instead of each form having its own sheet), that would be ideal.

Comment: I think your best bet is to use the spreadsheet to generate URLs that [pre-populate form fields](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160000?hl=en) such as "teacher name" and "student name" (or Student 1, Student 2, etc). These URLs follow a clear pattern (as I mentioned [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92979)), which makes it possible to generate them with a formula. I'm unclear on how you imagined a dropdown helping here: it would appear that only one student can be selected (hence evaluated) with this approach.

Comment: Did you look at the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)?
You can link several forms to the same spreadsheet but each will have it's own sheet. If you need everything in one sheet you could use a script to automatically combine those sheets.

Comment: You could ask this question in the G+ Community for Apps Script.  [Link - Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102471985047225101769)